# Magento2: getting customer access token

Tags: magento2, api

Creating (or say extending) an API where customer can login by Facebook/Google so I want get the same token which magento generates (same as if we login normally).

Reason is that if I will get that token then same I can use to access the other APIs (which magento has already developed)..

Is there anybody having idea ??
except Password I can give all the customer information..

Comment: Did you get a solution for problem? I am suffering from it. please check this link:  [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175480/get-token-authentication-for-customer-logged-with-facebook-twitter-magento-2]

Comment: Yeah.., I found the solution, do you need that?

Comment: Yes, Please....

Comment: so basically u need the token key after passing the customer data, correct ?
rest logic of validation will be your ?

Comment: Yes, I can save customer data from facebook or twitter, but I want to get token so i can call all api which request authorization. which validation part you mean?

Comment: u can have look at my answer on you question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to login bny customerid  but I am not sure about customer token.

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $session = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        if ($session->loginById($customerId)) {
            $session->regenerateId();
        }
```

customer will login by above code and now get customer data from session

```
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   $customerSession->getCustomerId();  // get Customer Id
   $customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
   $customerSession->getCustomer();
   $customerSession->getCustomerData();

   echo $customerSessionget->getCustomer()->getName();  // get  Full Name
   echo $customerSessionget->getCustomer()->getEmail(); // get Email
}
```

Comment: How can I call all APIs which request token ? I can't understand your answer, Do you mean I can use the ID generated without of token or what ?

Comment: Token is being generated dynamically, So if you want to generate token you have to follow same process as Customer module does.