# Get Token Authentication For Customer Logged With Facebook & Twitter : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

Dears, I created a custom REST API, So customer can login Via facebook and twitter through mobile app. The API consists of one service which take some parameters and email parameter and check if this email is found or not.

-If found, then return customer id.

-If not found, then insert email and other parameters (firstname, lastname, socialid, socialtype).

**My question**, I don't save password for the customer because the response return from facebook doest not contain password, so how to get token authentication, so I can do all operations which request customer token?

In normal, I can login and get token through:

**POST**

```
 https://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token?username=test@gmail.com&password=12345
```

and response will be token.

Comment: How did you added the info returned from facebook to the database?. Which table?

Comment: I used this plugin https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-social-login-extension/

Comment: @Jsparo30 Have you got solution for login facebook API. I am looking for same. Let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I understand from you question is, You have only email (and obviously some network specific secret key to validate i.e facebook key).

So You just need to load the customer by email id as below.

```
protected function getCustomerToken($emailId){
 /**
* @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer */
*/
$customer->loadByEmail($emailId);
if($customer->getId()){
        /**
        * @var \Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\TokenFactory $tokenModelFactory 
        */
        $customerToken = $this->tokenModelFactory->create();
        $tokenKey = $customerToken->createCustomerToken($customerId)->getToken();
        return $tokenKey;
}
return "YOU MSG FOR CUSTOMER NOT FOUND";
}
```

The above code should return the token key without password.

**Note:** Make sure you are doing proper & strong validating before generating the token & rest is already explained in **Franck's** answer .

Comment: hi, i am getting this error message in response {
  "message": "A customer website ID must be specified when using the website scope."
}

Comment: @AsharRiaz the problem is `Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer::loadByEmail`, here its checking if website is associated with customer.
May be the time customer was created account scope was global and later changed website.

Comment: @MohammadMujassam  i resolve this issue by adding $customer->setWebsiteId(1);  before loadByEmail method

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to pass the Facebook auth token in order to validate your customer.

Extend the native token authentication with your logic to validate the Facebook token.

Usefull information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623974/design-for-facebook-authentication-in-an-ios-app-that-also-accesses-a-secured-we

The same approach can works with Twitter.

Extend or create your own API endpoint in order to manage FB / Twitter Login.

The native code for token generation is located here :

**vendor/magento/module-integration/Model/CustomerTokenService.php:74**

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function createCustomerAccessToken($username, $password)
{
    $this->validatorHelper->validate($username, $password);
    $this->getRequestThrottler()->throttle($username, RequestThrottler::USER_TYPE_CUSTOMER);
    try {
        $customerDataObject = $this->accountManagement->authenticate($username, $password);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->getRequestThrottler()->logAuthenticationFailure($username, RequestThrottler::USER_TYPE_CUSTOMER);
        throw new AuthenticationException(
            __('You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.')
        );
    }
    $this->getRequestThrottler()->resetAuthenticationFailuresCount($username, RequestThrottler::USER_TYPE_CUSTOMER);
    return $this->tokenModelFactory->create()->createCustomerToken($customerDataObject->getId())->getToken();
}
```

Then you can modify the validation logic and the Magento customer ID retrieval in order to return a generated token.

Comment: Thank you, Do you mean I call facebook auth token directly. As Ex, to get customer info, I call API : `https://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/cus
tomers/me` and Header Params: `Authorization  Bearer {{facebook auth token }}`  ??

Comment: Not really. You can call the integration/customer/token API with username / FB token. Then extend the native call to check if the FB token is valid for this user. (FB user ID / FB token). If valid, then generate a native M2 Auth token for this user. Then use the M2 native token for the other native M2 API call.

Comment: Can you explain more with example? .. For `integration/customer/token API with username / FB token` which username ? magento 2 or facebook? .. Give more calarification for this part `Then extend the native call to check if the FB token is valid for this user. (FB user ID / FB token).`

Comment: You need to create your custom API, retrieve the native code for integration/customer/token. Put your own logic to validate the FB login, then try to match the internal Magento customer and generate the Magento 2 token. Usefull native code here : `\Magento\Integration\Model\CustomerTokenService::createCustomerAccessToken`

Comment: Open new question to have specific information about Magento 2

Comment: Please check:  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176362/get-integration-token-for-customer-comes-from-facebook-twitter-login-rest-api

Comment: It is the same question, you need to create your own API to retrieve the user registred with the Facebook ID and validate Facebook token then generate Magento token.

Answer (score 0):

If user is loggined

```
<?php


namespace Test\Module\Controller\Test;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;


class Token extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount
{
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
    */
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\TokenFactory $tokenModelFactory
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_tokenModelFactory = $tokenModelFactory;
        parent::__construct(
            $context
        );
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
        $customerToken = $this->_tokenModelFactory->create();
        echo "Customer-token=> ".$tokenKey = $customerToken->createCustomerToken($customerId)->getToken();
    }
}
```

If you need login without enter password

```
class AutoLoginManagement implements \Flo\Core\Api\AutoLoginManagementInterface
{

    protected $_customer;
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $_tokenModelFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\TokenFactory $tokenModelFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    )
    {
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_tokenModelFactory = $tokenModelFactory;
    }

    public function postAutoLogin($data)
    {

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        // Load customer
        $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($data['customer_id']);

        if(! $customer->getId()) {
            return 'Not Found';
        } else {
            // Load customer session
            $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
            $customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);

            $customerToken = $this->_tokenModelFactory->create();
            $tokenKey = $customerToken->createCustomerToken($customer->getId())->getToken();
            return $tokenKey;

        }

    }

}
```