# Magento 2, How to create API for customer login by using facebook

Tags: magento2.2, customer, rest-api

Using `Magento 2.2`, `API`. How to create login/logout into magento by using `Facebook`. I got user profile info form facebook and I need to use this info to get `Get Customer Token`.

Comment: Just pass those info your custom Login/Create API where based on customer email you can decide whether to login or create the new customer.

Comment: Can i generate `customer token` from new *customer without password*?

Comment: yes you can generate.

Comment: How to generate , plz show me?

Comment: please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175480/get-token-authentication-for-customer-logged-with-facebook-twitter-magento-2

Comment: @BongChannarith Have got solution for login facebook API. I am looking for same login API.