# Magento2 rest api add customer token in create customer api

Tags: magento-2.1

i am using
magento 2.1.1
php version 7.0

this is my payload and response.

[image]

i want to add customer token in the response and i am using following magento 2 api :

http://host/index.php/rest/default/V1/customers

Example (*)
in the response i want to add seesion id in following response :

```
{
"id": 2278,
"group_id": 1,
"created_at": "2018-11-13 14:06:24",
"updated_at": "2018-11-13 14:06:24",
"created_in": "Default Store View",
"email": "test1023@gmail.com",
"firstname": "test",
"lastname": "lastName",
"store_id": 1,
"website_id": 1,
"addresses": [],
"disable_auto_group_change": 0
"session_id": "b5la2wrgxx00oqu83yuvqdthnqjv1tmv"
}
```

Hope you guys understand my problem

Comment: Seeion id you mean customer token or PHP SESSION id ?

Comment: yes @MohammadMujassam, I want to add customer token in response data.

Comment: You can write plugin for this method to append the token Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement::createAccountWithPasswordHash(), And to generate the token refer this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175480/get-token-authentication-for-customer-logged-with-facebook-twitter-magento-2

Comment: @MohammadMujassam, can you please tell me from which file we get response data?

Comment: `Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement` this is model where buisness logic is there and `Magento\Customr\Api\AccountManagementInterface` this is interface. You can refer the Answer given by Ramkishan and accept the answer if that works.

Answer (score 2):

Create a afterCreateAccount plugin of AccountManagementInterface. You need to create a new customer attribute as well. Your plugin code will look like below.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class AddAccessToken
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\TokenFactory $tokenModelFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionFactory $customerExtensionFactory
    ) {
        $this->tokenModelFactory = $tokenModelFactory;
        $this->customerExtensionFactory = $customerExtensionFactory
    }

    /**
     * Add token to customer object
     *
     * @param   \Magento\Customr\Api\AccountManagementInterface $subject,
     * @param   \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer
     * @return  \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
     */
    public function afterCreateAccount(
        \Magento\Customr\Api\AccountManagementInterface $subject,
         \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer
    ) {
        $token = $this->tokenModelFactory->create()->createCustomerToken($customer->getId());
        $extensionAttributes = $customer->getExtensionAttributes();
        if($extensionAttributes === null) {
                $extensionAttributes = $this->customerExtensionFactory->create();
       }
        $extensionAttributes->setToken($token);
        $customer->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        return $customer;
    }

}
```

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Customr\Api\AccountManagementInterface">
    <plugin name="add_access_token" type="Vendot\Module\Plugin\AddAccessToken"/>
</type>
```

**extension_attributes.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
    <attribute code="token" type="string" />
</extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Go into module.xml file and update setup_version to 1.0.1 and run setup:upgrade command. Let me know if any more help needed.

Comment: Did it work for you @Nilesh

Comment: can you tell me how to add customer attribute and in which file?

Comment: Please check updated answer.

Comment: I have added eav attribute token as per your steps but getting following error :  **Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Data\\Customer::setToken() in /app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/AddAccessToken.php:26**

Comment: What error, I hope you are aware about setup scripts. if you are not then I would like to let you know that InstallData only runs when your module is installed first time. If you want to run this for already installed module then run this script in UpgradeData.php

Comment: attribute is not created yet let me update my answer a bit.

Comment: Please check updated answer.

Comment: the attribute is created also in the database when I create an InstallData.php file. getting the error of setToken() call to undefined method in the plugin file.

Comment: If your module is already installed then InstallData script not comes in action when you run setup upgrade. So you have to use UpgradeData in this case.

Comment: ok did all step now token attribute is there in my database. but when I run following API  for new customer account: `http://host/index.php/rest/default/V1/customers`            
         getting error in plugin file  **Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ::setToken()** in __afterCreateAccount method__

Comment: I just updated ny answer, you need to use $customer->setCustomAttribute('token', $token);

Comment: i just made changes. now getting new error **Class object does not exist**

Comment: Please give a min, I am updating my answer.

Comment: Hi @NileshThote Please check my updated answer again. just leave to use custom attribute.

Comment: i made changes in the code as per your updates but again getting new error **Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setToken() on null.**

Comment: remove generated folder at root then try. if still is there issue try to compile once. before that please check extension-attribute.xml file

Comment: I did it. but not working getting the same error.

Comment: Please check I updated plugin file. actually sometime getExtensionAttributes() null so you need to create object again in case it is null.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85836/discussion-on-answer-by-ramkishan-suthar-magento2-rest-api-add-customer-token-in).